# Examples of matrices $T$ and $A$ such that $T(\ker(A))\not\subset\ker(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ and let $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ .

> I look for an example of matrices $T$ and $A$  such that $T(\ker(A))\not\subset\ker(A)$.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take $\mathcal{H}= \mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard scalar product and choose the operators given by the following matrices:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
We can see that $\mathcal{N}(A)=vect\{(-1,1)\}$. So, $e=(-1,1)\in \mathcal{N}(A)$, but $ATe \notin \mathcal{N}(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

You need $T(\mathcal N(A)) \ne \{0\}$ (because $0 \in \mathcal N(A)$) and therefore $\mathcal N(A) \ne \{0\}$ either. So you must have a least 2 dimensions.

Hint 2:

> 2 dimensions is all you need.

Hint 3:

> Since $\mathcal N(A) \ne \{0\}, A$ needs to kill one dimension. But since we also don't want $\mathcal N(A) = \Bbb C^2, A$ should not kill the other.

Hint 4:

> $T$ should rotate $\mathcal N(A)$ into the dimension $A$ does not kill.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've already practically spelled the whole thing out. The space is $\Bbb C^2$, $A$ is *any* linear map whose image is a one-dimensional subspace (and therefore, whose null space is another 1 dimensional subspace). $T$ is any linear map that does not carry the particular direction of the null space to itself. I even specifically suggested a rotation to the image of $A$ as one example. If you can't come up with linear maps $A, T$ that meet these conditions, then you need to go back and study the basics. My giving them to you on a platter would just sink you even further over your head.